# SAS: Fuzzy Joins

Tags: sql, r, sas, data-manipulation

I have the following SQL query I am running in SAS:

```
proc sql;
create table my_table as
select a.*, b.* 
from table_a a
inner join table_b b
on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3 and a.id1 = b.id1)
or a.id2 = b.id2;
quit;
```

**My Question:** I am trying to replace "a.id1 = b.id1" with "a.id1 FUZZY EQUAL a.id1" (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=functions-fuzzy-string-search), and have this an "explicit
create table my_table as
select a.*, b.*
from table_a a
inner join table_b b
on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3 where le_dst(a.id1, b.id1) = 1 )
or a.id2 = b.id2;
quit;

But I am new to SAS and do not know how to do this properly.

Can someone please show me how to do this? Are there any other common "fuzzy join" functions that are well suited for this kind of problem?

Thanks!

**Note1:** The tables look like this:

```
> table_a

    id1 id2     date_1
1 123 A  11 2010-01-31
2 123BB  12 2010-01-31
3  12 5  14 2015-01-31
4 12--5  13 2018-01-31

> table_b

     id1 id2     date_2     date_3
1   0123 111 2009-01-31 2011-01-31
2   1233 112 2010-01-31 2010-01-31
3 125  .  14 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
4   125_ 113 2010-01-31 2020-01-31
```

**Note 2:** R Code used to create these tables for this example (in my original problem, the dates appear in "factor" variable type within R):

```
table_a = data.frame(id1 = c("123 A", "123BB", "12 5", "12--5"), id2 = c("11", "12", "14", "13"),
date_1 = c("2010-01-31","2010-01-31", "2015-01-31", "2018-01-31" ))

table_a$id1 = as.factor(table_a$id1)
table_a$id2 = as.factor(table_a$id2)
table_a$date_1 = as.factor(table_a$date_1)

table_b = data.frame(id1 = c("0123", "1233", "125  .", "125_"), id2 = c("111", "112", "14", "113"),
date_2 = c("2009-01-31","2010-01-31", "2010-01-31", "2010-01-31" ),
date_3 = c("2011-01-31","2010-01-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-01-31" ))


table_b$id1 = as.factor(table_b$id1)
table_b$id2 = as.factor(table_b$id2)
table_b$date_2 = as.factor(table_b$date_2)
table_b$date_3 = as.factor(table_b$date_3)
```

Comment: Do you have SQL code that works in Netezza?  Why aren't you using `from connection to` in your SAS code to run that SQL in the remote database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the SQL into the remote database.

```
proc sql;
  connect to netezza .... ;
  create table sastable as 
    select * from connection to netezza
      (
select a.*, b.* 
  from table_a a
  inner join table_b b
    on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3)
      and (le_dst(a.id1, b.id1) = 1 or a.id2 = b.id2)
     )
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Yes. fill in the CONNECT statement with the credentials that work for your database.

Answer (score 1):

Page 258 of the documentation [SAS®
9.4 SQL Procedure
User’s Guide, Fourth
Edition](https://documentation.sas.com/api/docsets/sqlproc/9.4/content/sqlproc.pdf?locale=en) shows two forms of `CONNECT` statement syntax:

- **CONNECT TO** *dbms-name <AS alias>

  <(connect-statement-argument-1=value-1 <connect-statement-argument-2=value-2
  …>)> 

  <(database-connection-argument-1=value-1 <database-connectionargument-2=value-2 …>)>;*
- **CONNECT USING** *libref <AS alias>*;

Replace *italics* with your actual values and items between <> are optional.